# Javascript / AJAX - Send Data to Server w/o Headers?

Tags: javascript, ajax, header

JS - Is there a way to send data to the server backend *without* headers?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the http headers are mandatory.

If you are using a browser you cannot control the http headers sent by the browser.